# Rotation of free to rotate rigid bodies

Tags: rotation

I recently came across this statement in a book that the line joining the point of suspension and center of mass of a body should be parallel to the acceleration due to gravity(g or more precisely, g effective). Why is this so?
Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score -1):

Recall that we adjust other Forces or acceleration effect in g effective. So there are only 2 External Forces on the rigid body, in the frame of body.

1. Tension due to string
2. Effective Gravitational force

Now since tension always applies along the string, it will align with effective g during equilibrium.